# jQuery toggle for nested menu - how to keep open on page load?

Tags: jquery, menu, nested, slidetoggle, pageload

I am using a nested vertical navigation with jQuery toggle to slide open each section.

If I open up the nested sections and navigate to a new page, how do I keep the current state of the menu open on the new page? At the moment it reloads and closes all the sections.

I have tried using jQuery cookie plugin  but it remembered the state of the menu per page, so for example it was open on one page but not on another.

Here is a code pen example of what I'm doing (version without any cookie, just jQuery toggle)

http://codepen.io/codeycodecode/pen/hxfws/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slide").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).parent().children(".slideContent");
    $(target).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="depth-1">
      <a class="slide header" href="#">Identity</a>  
      <ul class="slideContent" >
          <li class="depth-2"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="depth-1" >
      <a class="slide header" href="#">Products</a>
      <ul class="slideContent">
        <li class="depth-2">
          <a href="#">Widgets</a>
        </li>
        <li class="depth-2">
          <a class="slide header" href="#">Desktop Apps</a>
          <ul class="slideContent ">
            <li class="depth-3">
              <a href="#">Email App</a>
            </li>
            <li class="depth-3">
              <a  class="slide header" href="#">Editing App</a>
              <ul class="slideContent">
                <li class="depth-4">
                  <a href="#">Color</a>
                </li>
                <li class="depth-4">
                  <a href="#">Icons</a>
                </li>
                <li class="depth-4">
                  <a href="#">Typeface</a>
                </li>
                <li class="depth-4">
                  <a href="#">Prototype</a>
                </li>
                <li class="depth-4">
                  <a class="slide header" href="#">Development</a>
                  <ul class="slideContent"> 
                      <li class="depth-5" ><a  href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="depth-5" ><a  href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="depth-5" ><a  href="#">Link</a></li>   
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>  
            </li>
          </ul>  
        </li>
        <li class="depth-2">
          <a href="#">Mobile Apps</a>
        </li>
      </ul> 

    </li>
  </ul>   
</nav>
```

Comment: Use a session cookie.

Comment: Thanks, I need some help incorporating it with the toggle js:
`$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slide").click(function(){
    
    var target = $(this).parent().children(".slideContent");
    $(target).slideToggle();
  });
});`